# how to close menu program programmatically in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, menu, alert

Expectation:
when receiving a message from server side, the view  will show a alert.

Problem:
there are several components like textFields with **menu** in one view,
when I *expand a menu* and keep it unfold status, the alert does not be shown properly after receiving a message from server side.
of course, when i *fold(or close) menu*, in other word, keep it in folded status, the alert view will be shown properly.

```
   struct MenuView: View {
    @State private var name : String = ""
    @State private var count : Int = 0
    @State private var toggle : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $name)
                .alert(isPresented: $toggle) {
                    Alert(title: Text("title"),
                                    message: Text("message"),
                                    dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
            Menu {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
                Text("3")
            } label: {
                Text("Top menu1")
            }
            Spacer()

        }
        .onAppear {
            // to simulate message from server side after certain seconds.
            // before it is deadline., tap [Top menu1] link quickly and keep it on.
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                print("toggle is true.").  
                toggle = true       
            }
        }
            
    }
}
```

Question:

1. how can I make unfold menu folded programmatically
2. if  no better way to fold menu programmtically, what is your suggestion to show alert view when menu is unfold.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a rather hacky solution.

Use a `State` to control whether the `Menu` appears at all. The idea is that if we make the menu disappear for just a moment, and then make it appear it again, it will definitely end up in the "unfolded" state.

```
@State var showMenu = true

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("", text: $name)
        
        if showMenu {
            Menu {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
                Text("3")
            } label: {
                Text("Top menu1")
            }.onDisappear {
                // when the menu disappears, immediately show it again
                showMenu = true
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    ...
}
```

When you receive messages from the server, hide the menu:

```
showMenu = false

// can't show the alert immediately - the menu needs to disappear first!
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    toggle = true
}
```